# Indexing with tex4ebook showing undefined control sequence

Tags: indexing, tex4ht, tex4ebook

I use tex4ebooks the first time. I thought today that I managed to get indexing with it, but then at the final step an encoding problem arose, which I already solved with the help of the forum.

But now an undefined control sequence come with the minimal example as following:

The config for tex4ebook shows this:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,no-cut,3,info}
\usepackage{indexing4ht}
\usepackage{gettitlestring}
\makeatletter
\Configure{@author}{\let\footnote\@gobble}
\Configure{@title}{\let\footnote\@gobble}
\makeatother
\GetTitleStringDisableCommands{%
\renewcommand\textbf[1]{#1}%
\renewcommand\LaTeX{LaTeX}
}
\begin{document}
\Configure{DocumentLanguage}{de}
% You can also add more authors to your ebook metadata:
\Configure{OpfMetadata}{\HCode{<dc:creator>An author</dc:creator>}}
\Configure{OpfMetadata}{\HCode{<dc:title>A title</dc:title>}}
\Configure{OpfMetadata}{\HCode{<dc:publisher>A publisher</dc:publisher>}}
\Configure{OpfMetadata}{\HCode{<dc:contributor>Somethin</dc:contributor>}}
\Configure{OpfMetadata}{\HCode{<dc:date opf:event='Originalausgabe'>2023</dc:date>}}
\EndPreamble
```

The indexing4ht.sty is as follows:

```
\ProvidesPackage{indexing4ht}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{gettitlestring}
% Befehl zum Abrufen der vollständigen Abschnittsnummer für den aktuellen Abschnittsbefehl
\newcommand\getCurrentSectionNumber{%
  \ifnum\c@section=0 %
  \thechapter
  \else
  \ifnum\c@subsection=0 %
  \thesection
  \else
  \ifnum\c@subsubsection=0 %
  \thesubsection
  \else
  \thesubsubsection
  \fi
  \fi
  \fi
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xdy}
(define-attributes (("default" "definition" "textbf")))
(define-location-class "sec-num" :var
 ("arabic-numbers" 
 :sep "."  "arabic-numbers"
 :sep "."  "arabic-numbers"
 :sep "."  "arabic-numbers"
 :sep "."  "arabic-numbers"))
(require "texindy.xdy")
(markup-keyword :open "\idxkeyword{" :close "}")
(markup-locref :open "\idxlocator{" :close "}")
(markup-locref :open "\textbf{\idxlocator{" :close "}}" :attr "textbf")
(markup-locref :open "\textbf{\idxlocator{" :close "}}" :attr "definition")
\end{filecontents*}
\endinput
```

An the indexing4ht.4ht shows:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{imakeidx}{%
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand\:wrindex[3]{%
      \edef\th@idx@entry{\detokenize{#2}}
        \imki@wrindexentry{#1}{\th@idx@entry}{#3}
    }
    \makeatother
}{%ToDo: Provide configuration for index writing without imakeidx
    \newcommand\:wrindex[3]{}
}

% because imakeidx has support for multiple indices, we need to select a
% right one
\NewConfigure{indexname}{1}
% default index name is \jobname

% configure variable which is saved on every index call
% section mark is used by default, other possible values may be paragraphs, or
% links to individual index entries
\NewConfigure{indexvalue}{1}
\Configure{indexvalue}{\getCurrentSectionNumber}
\NewConfigure{indexidentifier}{1}
\Configure{indexidentifier}{\CurSecHaddr}

% we need to suppress adding of multiple identical identifiers
\edef\curseccnt{}
\renewcommand\index[2][]{%
  \ifx|#1|%
     \Configure{indexname}{\jobname}%
   \else\Configure{indexname}{#1}%
     \fi%
  \:wrindex{\a:indexname}{#2}{\a:indexvalue}
    % save identifier only if it haven't been used yet
  \expandafter\ifcsname usedsec\a:indexvalue\endcsname
    \else%
    \Tag{sec\a:indexvalue}{\a:indexidentifier}
  \fi%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname usedsec\a:indexvalue\endcsname{yes}
  \let\curseccnt\newseccnt
}

% print index locators. make links to destinations in document
\newcommand\idxlocator[1]{%
\ifTag{sec#1}{\a:locatorlink{\Ref{sec#1}}{}#1\b:locatorlink}{#1}%
%\ifTag{sec#1}{\Link{\Ref{sec#1}}{}#1\EndLink}{#1}%
\typeout{\LikeRef{sec#1}}}

\NewConfigure{locatorlink}{2}
\Configure{locatorlink}{\Link}{\EndLink}

% to support crossreferencess, we save index keyword with unique identifier

\GetTitleStringSetup{expand}
\GetTitleStringDisableCommands{%
  \renewcommand\LaTeX{LaTeX}
}

\newcount\idxkwdcnt
\LinkCommand\IdxKWLink{span,href,id}
\newcommand\idxkeyword[1]{%
  \global\advance\idxkwdcnt by 1\relax%
  % use tags only one time
  \GetTitleString{#1}%
  \ifcsdef{idxkw\GetTitleStringResult}{}%
  %{\Tag{idxkw#1}{idxkw\the\idxkwdcnt}}%
  {\expandafter\Tag\expandafter{idxkw\GetTitleStringResult}{idxkw\the\idxkwdcnt}}%
  \csgdef{idxkw\GetTitleStringResult}{x}%
  \a:IdxKW{}{idxkw\the\idxkwdcnt}#1\b:IdxKW}


\NewConfigure{IdxKW}{2}
\Configure{IdxKW}{\IdxKWLink}{\EndIdxKWLink}

  
\renewcommand\see[1]{%
  \GetTitleString{#1}%
  \a:see\ \ifTag{idxkw#1}{\a:seeLink{\Ref{idxkw\GetTitleStringResult}}{}#1\b:seeLink}{#1}
}  

% make link configurable, in order to enable user to add custom parameters
\NewConfigure{seeLink}{2}
\Configure{seeLink}{\Link}{\EndLink}

\NewConfigure{see}{1}
\Configure{see}{\textit{siehe}}

\renewcommand\seealso[1]{%
  \GetTitleString{#1}%
  \a:seealso\ \ifTag{idxkw#1}{\a:seeAlsoLink{\Ref{idxkw\GetTitleStringResult}}{}#1\b:seeAlsoLink}{#1}
}

\NewConfigure{seeAlsoLink}{2}
\Configure{seeAlsoLink}{\Link}{\EndLink}

\NewConfigure{seealso}{1}
\Configure{seealso}{\textit{siehe auch}}
```

And finally the makefile mymakef.mk4 is this:

```
if mode=="draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:xindy {modules={"duden-utf8"}}
  Make:biber {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end
```

Then I run first

```
tex4ebook -a debug -c myconfig.cfg -m index -e mymakef.mk4 Sourcename.tex
```

And then call xindy manually to get the .ind file

```
call xindy -L german -C duden-utf8 -I latex -M Sourcename.xdy Sourcename.idx
```

And then I run tex4ebook again an get the undefined controll sequence error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.9   \item \idxkeyword
                       {Ende}, \idxlocator{4}
```

The tex-file finallly is this as minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\usepackage[xindy,noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc=false,columns=1,noautomatic,title=Alphabetisches Verzeichnis]
\usepackage[hyperindex=true,
pdfauthor={Autor},
pdftitle={Titel},
pdfkeywords={Philosophy}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents    
    \section{Übungen}
    Praxis und Übungen\index{Uebungen@Übungen}
    
    \section{Abschnitt Eins}
    
    Zwei Welten\index{Welten} und Ähren im Feld.
    
    \section{Abschnitt Zwei}    
    
    Beginn und Ende\index{Ende}
    
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

Maybe someone knows the clue to the door. Thank you.

Thomkrates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing is now supported out of the box in TeX4ht, so you don't really need the `indexing4ht` package. You can remove it from your `.cfg` file. I also had to remove `Make:biber {}` from your build file, because you don't use BibLaTeX in the example, and it resulted in an error.

For German-Duden, try this build file:

```
if mode=="draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:xindy {language="german-duden"}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end
```

The up-to-date information about indexing is available in this [how to](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Howto.html#indexing).

This is how your index looks in Calibre:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, how did you do that? I removed indexinght.sty and Make:biber {}. And started from scratch, with 1. tex4ebook like above mentioned 2. xindy like above mentioned and 3. again tex4ebook. But I get the same error message. Do I have the newest tex4ebook version? --> Version 0.3h. Is this new enought?

Comment: xindy shows the info lines: "Encountered unexpected char '\' on line 1
Encountered unexpected char 'b' on line 1
Encountered unexpected char 'e' on line 1
Encountered unexpected char 'f' on line 1 ..." Is this again an encoding problem?

Comment: @Thomkrates you don't need to run Xindy manually, it is called automatically from the build file, with necessary post-processing steps.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I do not got your result. The index in the epub is without hyperref. And additionally with the minimal example, I got two table of contents in the epub und doubled. - Is this intentious? - The latest version of tex4ebook is 0.3i. I copied the files in appropriate folder.

Comment: @Thomkrates yes, the double TOC is intentional, this fixes a bug with split chapters, where the TOC was in a separate page and there was no way how to go from the main HTML file to subpages. So now the main TOC is printed in the main page, but you will get an extra TOC when you use `\tableofcontents`. You can disable the second TOC using `\ifdefined\HCode\else\tableofcontents\fi`.

Comment: @Thomkrates regarding the index, maybe `xindy` fails with an error? What do you get in the terminal output? I know that there is a lot of text in the output, but you should get some interesting info after the first run of LaTeX, after `[DEBUG]   xindy: Loading module: duden-utf8` line.

Comment: No xindy does not fail, shows only the above "... Encountered unexpected char '-' on line 5..." which reads the .idx file and does not expect anything there. I got a correct .ind file which show the index code for hyper reference in epub. But after that, with tex4ebook, there is the error message "Undefined control sequence ..." like already communicated.

Comment: @Thomkrates if you get the error about `\idxkeyword`, it could be that you still include `indexing4ht` in the `cfg` file?

Comment: I don't think so, I deleted the  \usepackage{indexing4ht} tag. But maybe there is the need for deleting produced files out of earlier compliations with tex4ebook? - I try it this evening. Thank you. I will be back here an report in the evening.

Comment: I now deleted all files, except the sourcename.tex and ran tex4ebook once. Some files have been produced. The result is insufficient, since the index in without hyperref in the epub. Next I tried manually again xindy with the above command line option, but it gives the error the the sourcename.xdy is lacking, which is put after the -m option. Is this correctly run? Or had I need to get after the first tex4ebook run the correct epub, that you already produced out of my minimal example? Thank you for assistance and hints.

Comment: @Thomkrates Xindy needs to be called from the `.mk4` file, because it does some pre-processing and post-processing, to introduce links. Can you update your question with the `ind` file produced after the  `tex4ebook` run?

Comment: There is no `.ind` file and no `.xdy` file after first tex4ebook run. I think the `mk4` file need a better command line for `Make:xindy` like above already told.

Comment: @Thomkrates ah, so it seems that there is some error in the Xindy run. I've updated my answer with the build file which works for me.

Comment: Thank you Michal, I'll try it this evening. It seems that `language=...` is the replacement for `modules=...`. And also `german-duden` replaces `duden-utf8`. I'm keen to know, if all runs well on my system. I will report.

Comment: Oh, it turns out to be a bit frustrating: It doesnt work with the recent changes that you suggested. There is also still no `.xdy` file and no `.ind` file. In the epub view no index is seen und in the toc no `Alphabetisches Verzeichnis`, which is the title of the index an needs to be set with `\printindex`. It seems as if this last tag is omitted. Do you have any suggestions what needs to be done?

Comment: @Thomkrates there doesn't need to be any `.xdy` file, but `.ind` should be there definitely. I think I will need to see the whole terminal output from `tex4ebook`, there must be some error message or something.

Comment: Ok., I copied the tex4ebook output in a txt-document and could send it to you. But I do  not know how. Thank you for assistance.

Comment: I have found the error: It hasnt been an error, the `.mk4` file was not found. And I found that it has been named `buildfile..mk4` (with two dots) out of unknown reason. Now I get an `Alphabetisches Verzeichnis` that looks identical to yours here in the answer. But in the `toc` I got two links for `Alphabetisches Verzeichnis`. This may not be intentional. How could this be fixed? Thank you for your appreciated help.

Comment: I also found the solution. I changed the `\makeindex[options...]` to option in `intoc=false` since I got it `true`. Now the indexing with tex4ebook is solved in my `Testdocument.tex` and will try it in my real book.tex projects. Thank you, Michal, it was a pleasure communicating with you. I surely will come back soon with other questions, and will try this know how now for my projects. With best wishes. Thomkrates.

Comment: @Thomkrates I am glad that you found the culprit. It makes sense now, as when loading of the build file fails, the default build sequence is used.

Comment: I'm glad too. But one thing is in common between our output: At the charakter `U` in the index `Alphabetisches Verzeichnis` it seems as if a `\baselineskip` is lacking. In my real project this happens at the character `B` Some days ago I can remember that somewhere else this has been addressed, but I do not find it. Is it something to live with? Or are there any solution for it? Thank you for your assistance again.

Comment: @Thomkrates it is a bug in TeX4ht, I will fix it in the sources, but the changed files are too large to post them here. It will be best to wait for the update of TeX Live.

Comment: Ok, thank you, Michal, for your work and dedicated commitment.